# Como recuperar o último pagamento?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tenho a seguinte tabela no meu banco:

```
"financeiro
    financeiro_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    financeiro_pagamento DATE,
    financeiro_pid INT,
    financeiro_valor INT,
";
```

Nessa tabela eu registro os pagamentos que o meu sistema recebe, depois uso a seguinte Query para me retornar os valores:

```
"SELECT *FROM login lo 
  inner join financeiro fi on lo.login_id = fi.financeiro_pid 
  Order by financeiro_pagamento";
```

Essa Query pega o `financeiro_pid` e faz as junção com a tabela `login` para saber quem pagou, só que eu preciso que cada registro igual dessa tabela me retorne apenas o último pagamento da pessoa. Com essa Query estou pegando todos os pagamentos, mas eu queria apenas o último pagamento do usuário.

Obs.: `financeiro_pid` é onde eu registro a chave do usuário.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query abaixo deve fazer o que desejas. Irá pegar apenas os pagamentos mais recentes de cada cliente (`MAX()`):

```
SELECT * FROM financeiro fi 
   inner join login lo on lo.login_id = fi.financeiro_pid
WHERE
   fi.financeiro_pagamento = (SELECT MAX(fi2.financeiro_pagamento) FROM financeiro fi2 where fi2.financeiro_pid = fi.financeiro_pid)
ORDER BY
   financeiro_pagamento
```

Comment: Top resolveu valeu pelo salve

Answer (score 0):

Não uses `max()`

Utiliza o `last_insert_id()` :

Razão:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8345399/is-it-conceptually-right-to-do-a-select-maxid-etc-for-finding-the-last-insert

Yes, there is some relationship between max id and most recent insert, but consider the following:

what if the most recently inserted row was deleted?